# Edit static page

Tags: wordpress

So I volunteer to a non-profit organization and ocasionally have to edit a Wordpress Theme. This one is pretty different to what I'm used so sometimes I get stuck.
We have a static page displaying the last two posts. They all come from the "Stories" category.
[image]

When we reach the page, it shows the last two posts. So far so good. I can even hit the "Edit page" to... edit it!
[image]

I edit it and add a lot of stuff but it never is displayed in the live page, in the stories address. It keeps showing just the two posts.
  [image]
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

- Make your changes
- publish the edited page
- leave the editor (close the tab)
- check the page
- Does the live vesrsion change?

  - yes? problem solved
  - no? Continue below
- open the editor one more time.
- are the changes you just made still visible in the editor?

  - if yes, then you need to clear your cache to see the changes in the live version
  - if no, then your changes are not being saved.